# How do I stop my accordion from popping the first time it's clicked?

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-click-event

I have a problem with my accordion. The first time I click any of the title bars to collapse that item, it has a sharp pop to close it. I'm using slideUp(), but it doesn't appear to be used initially. If I keep clicking the title bar for that item, slideUp()/slideDown() starts to work.

Additionally, my approach is not very efficient for reusability. If you look at the click event, I am creating it for each accordion item. How do I set it so that whether it is '`item1`', '`item2`', '`item3`', and more, the accordion will work for each item without having to create a new click event for each?

I have a jsfiddle posted here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jfd9n/1/

Thank you for your help!

```
// Accordion Plugin
(function($){
    $.fn.scaccordion = function(options){

        var defaults = {
            // Variables Here
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $('div.accordionitem').addClass('active');
        $('div.accordionitem').slideDown();
        console.log('Add class: active to all div.accordionitem elements.')

        // Click Event for item1: Open
        $(this).find('div.accordionitem.item1').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log('Accordion Item 1 Clicked');

            if ($('div.accordionitem.item1').hasClass('active')) {
                $('div.accordionitem.item1 div.accordion_content').slideUp();
                $('div.accordionitem.item1').removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $('div.accordionitem.item1 div.accordion_content').slideDown();
                $('div.accordionitem.item1').addClass('active');
            }
        });

        // Click Event for item2: Open
        $(this).children('div.accordionitem.item2').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log('Accordion Item 2 Clicked');

            if ($('div.accordionitem.item2').hasClass('active')) {
                $('div.accordionitem.item2 div.accordion_content').slideUp();
                $('div.accordionitem.item2').removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $('div.accordionitem.item2 div.accordion_content').slideDown();
                $('div.accordionitem.item2').addClass('active');
            }
        });

        // Click Event for item1: Open
        $(this).children('div.accordionitem.item3').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            console.log('Accordion Item 3 Clicked');

            if ($('div.accordionitem.item3').hasClass('active')) {
                $('div.accordionitem.item3 div.accordion_content').slideUp();
                $('div.accordionitem.item3').removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $('div.accordionitem.item3 div.accordion_content').slideDown();
                $('div.accordionitem.item3').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('div.taccholder').scaccordion();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this see update [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jfd9n/2/)

Your code:

```
// Accordion Plugin
(function($){
    $.fn.scaccordion = function(options){

        var defaults = {
            // Variables Here
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $('div.accordionitem').addClass('active');
        console.log('Add class: active to all div.accordionitem elements.')

        // Click Event for item1: Open
        $(this).find('div.accordionitem').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var self = $(this);
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

                $(this).find('.accordion_content').slideUp(300, function () {
                    self.removeClass('active');
                });
            } else {

                $(this).find('.accordion_content').slideDown(300, function () {
                self.addClass('active');    
                });
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('div.taccholder').scaccordion();
```

Comment: That definitely did the trick! That's so much. Works like a charm.

Comment: @ScriptsConnect if answer helped you, please select it as best answer!

Comment: Done. Sorry I forgot about that. I hit the up bottom only. The check mark is now green!